80% charge limit on Pixel 8?
I've seen multiple posts on Reddit from Pixel 8 Pro users, claiming that the December Feature Drop for Pixels enabled an 80% battery charge limit feature.
The setting looks like this:

Does the regular Pixel 8 not support this feature? My battery settings look like this:


I have a pixel 6a and was able to find the menu (1st screenshot) you're looking for after clicking on "Adaptive Charging" in the "Battery" menu (2nd screenshot). Then, once I clicked on "Adaptive Charging" it changed to "Charging optimization."

Hey it just changed for me too! That's so weird

@Protectorone A lot of updates come via google play services now, this might be why it seems to suddenly change.
